# Lex: Gather all text not defined in rules

Tags: formatting, state, flex-lexer, lex

I'm trying to gather all text that is not defined by a previous rule into a string and prefix it with a formatting string using lex.  I'm wondering if there's a standard way of doing this.

For example, say I have the rules:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4  {printf("%s%s", "<>", yytext);}
[0-9]+  {printf("%s%s", "{}", yytext);}
everything else  {printf("%s%s", "[]", yytext);}
```

And I attempt to lex the string:

```
word1 this is some other text ; word2 98 foo bar .
```

I would want this to produce the following when run through the lexer:

```
<>word1[] this is some other text ; <>word2[] {}98[] foo bar .
```

I attempted to do this using states, but realize I can't determine when to stop the check, like:

```
%x OTHER

%%
. {yymore(); BEGIN OTHER;}
<OTHER>.|\n  yymore();
<OTHER>how to determine when to end?  {printf("%s%s", "[]", yytex); BEGIN INITIAL;}
```

What is a good way to do this?  Is there someway to continue as long as another rule isn't met?

Comment: @ rici I tried something like `.|\n  printf("%s%s", "[]", yytext);` but this prefixes each character with `[]`.  I'd like to continue reading anything not defined in the previous rules and prefix everything read with `[]`.  So, instead of `word1 foo bar word2` lexed as `<>word1[] []foo[] []bar[] <>word2` I'd like it to be `<>word1[] foo bar <>word2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no "standard" solution, but a simple one is to keep a bit of context (the prefix last printed) and use that to decide whether or not to print a new prefix. For example, you could use a custom printer like this:

```
enum OutputType { NO_TOKEN = 0, WORD, NUMBER, OTHER };
void print_with_prefix(enum OutputType type, const char* token) {
  static enum OutputType prev = NO_TOKEN;
  const char* prefix = "";
  switch (type) {
    case WORD: prefix = "<>"; break;
    case NUMBER: prefix = "{}"; break;
    case OTHER: if (prev != OTHER) prefix = "[]"; break;
    default: assert(false);
  }
  prev = type;
  printf("%s%s", prefix, token);
}
```

Then you just need to change the calls to `printf` to invoke `print_with_prefix` instead (and, as written, to supply an enum value instead of a string).

For the `OTHER` case, you then don't need to do anything special to accumulate the token. Just

```
.   { print_with_prefix(OTHER, yytext); }
```

(I'm skating over the handling of whitespace and newlines, but it's just conceptual.)

Comment: @ rici  I think I see what you're suggesting.  I'll experiment with it and try to make it work.  Thanks for all the help.